# Have connected to other website but am having trouble connecting to a AWS webpage via sim900 using arduino

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, arduino, sim900

I have connected to other websites but have been able to connect to AWS I have seen others had this issue before me but none of the threads I found were answered. I am hoping someone has suggestion I can post the code if necessary. Is there a special way to connect to the AWS website? The goal of the project is to send data to a web page which was created using Amazons AWS services. We are using an  Access point  and are using a Json format.

Answer (score 0):

To establish a connection with AWS you must need a secured connection (https TLS 1.2) but the SIM900 firmware only provide TLS 1.0 (see the doc here : https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/SIM900_HTTPS%20AT%20Command%20Set_V1%2000.pdf)

I think I see somebody with the same configuration than yours (Arduino + sim900) who used a lib to connect to AWS.

Or you can establish a TCP connection with AWS and then use a lib to handshake and send data with TLS 1.2 protocol. More informations about TCP and TLS : https://medium.facilelogin.com/nuts-and-bolts-of-transport-layer-security-tls-2c5af298c4be